# Dns server name with vps directspace

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind

I apologize about my english.

I have vps `directspace.net` not private ip, when I buy this I put `ns1.computereconomy.com` and `ns2.computereconomy.com`

I am trying to make a dns server but is hard. I have just 2 ip's, no internal ip. If I go in `ssh` and write `ping ns1.computereconomy.com`, the ping is ok but in remote no ping and in remoto the reply ping is:

> 64 bytes from agarradao1.agarradao.com.br (174.140.166.246): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=218 ms

I dont know why this `agarradao1.agarradao.com.br`

This is my `ifconfig`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:71 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:71 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5494 (5.3 KiB)  TX bytes:5494 (5.3 KiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: 2605:ea00:1:1::bd8b:96a5/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2605:ea00:1:1::9198:8cb9/128 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:147046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:139211 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:10912649 (10.4 MiB)  TX bytes:61771870 (58.9 MiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:174.140.166.246  P-t-P:174.140.166.246  Bcast:174.140.166.246  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1

venet0:1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:69.163.40.59  P-t-P:69.163.40.59  Bcast:69.163.40.59  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Someone can help me for make good configuration bind for make multidomain like 20

I want to fully manage dns because I want create for my client subdomain self

Comment: venet0:0 ... inet addr: **174.140.166.246**

Answer (score 0):

The "agarradao1.agarradao.com.br." is a *reverse* dns entry. It will have been set up by whoever the IP address "174.140.166.246" belongs to, or has control of.

Your DNS server at "174.140.166.246", or "ns1.computerecononmy.com" is responding and is valid from the outside world.

You should modify your permissions on the DNS server so that anyone cannot request a full DNS zone. Example below for further explanation.

```
root@xxxxxx:~# dig @174.140.166.246 AXFR computereconomy.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> @174.140.166.246 AXFR computereconomy.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
computereconomy.com.    38400   IN      SOA     computereconomy.com. computereconomy.gmail.com. 1330966037 10800 3600 604800 38400
computereconomy.com.    38400   IN      NS      ns1.computereconomy.com.
computereconomy.com.    38400   IN      NS      ns2.computereconomy.com.
computereconomy.com.    38400   IN      NS      computereconomy.com.
computereconomy.com.    38400   IN      A       174.140.166.246
ftp.computereconomy.com. 38400  IN      A       174.140.166.246
www.computereconomy.com. 38400  IN      A       174.140.166.246
computereconomy.com.    38400   IN      SOA     computereconomy.com. computereconomy.gmail.com. 1330966037 10800 3600 604800 38400
;; Query time: 90 msec
;; SERVER: 174.140.166.246#53(174.140.166.246)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 19 00:48:37 2012
;; XFR size: 8 records (messages 1, bytes 237)
```